# Django forms stop form processing on ValidationError

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm designing a Django form with recaptcha and custom cleaning method for address field.

I want to stop form processing on first ValidationError in other words I don't want to execute **clean_address** method if recaptcha is bad.

For recaptcha I using [django-recaptcha](https://pypi.org/project/django-recaptcha/).

My form:

```py
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

from .models import Server, Category
from .utils.status_manager import ServerStatus


class AddServerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'checkbox'}),
                                           error_messages={
                                               'required': 'You need to select server type'
                                           },
                                           choices=[(c.pk, c.name) for c in Category.objects.all()]
                                           )

    def clean_address(self):
        address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        server = Server.objects.filter(address=address).exists()
        if server:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Server is on the list")
        if not ServerStatus(address).is_server_on():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Server is offline")
        return address

    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = ['address']
```

View:

```py
class AddServer(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    template_name = 'add_server.html'
    login_url = '/users/discord/login'
    form_class = AddServerForm

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        errors = get_form_errors(form)
        for error in errors:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, error)
        return super(AddServer, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        server = form.save()
        self.success_url = f'/servers/{server.id}'
        return super(AddServer, self).form_valid(form)
```

For now on ValidationError or if recaptcha is bad form still processes.

Answer (score 0):

You have method  `def clean_address(self):` but you have not added `address` fields in the top

Your forms will not `save` in the database and even it will not do further processing if you validate like this way:

```
def clean_captcha(self, value):
    ##write some validation logic and raise error
    return value
```

and to validate all the fields, you use this method:

```
def clean(self, data):
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning

Comment: I don't need to add address field on top because it's ModelForm. Raising ValidationError in clean methods don't stopping form processing.